# Pass multiple attribute values to filter products

Tags: filter, collection-filtering

How I can pass more than one attribute values at a time to filter products like attached image instead of filtering products using default functionality of selecting one attribute at a time?

[image]

Comment: check this : https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html

Comment: you have to rewrite this class Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price for the price attributes..

Answer (score 1):

This is a brad subject. I doubt you will get a fully working solution as an answer.
I can recommend you 2 extensions that I've used before. Both of them work nicely. They are not free but I think they are worth the money.

- http://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus
- https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html

Both of them do what you need and much more.

Comment: I think in those extensions also I need to do the modification as using those extensions if I'm checking a checkbox, products will be filtered?  Though I want to  select more than one attribute value then filter the product. any recommended approach to achieve it?

Comment: Nope. I have no other idea. That's the best I can do.

Comment: I am sorry but these are two terrible extensions, they are really bad written. You should look into https://www.bubbleshop.net/uk/magento-layer-seo-ajax.html, it does exactly what you're after and it's very lightweight

Comment: @Mayers. I've used them before and worked nicely. I had some issues with the manadev extension on an instance with 30+ websites and 40k+ products but for small and medium websites it worked nicely.

Comment: @Marius Have you looked at the code though? It probably works, but I had to remove it from a lot of customers' site due to impact on performance and awful quality code.

Comment: @Mayers I cannot contradict you there.